# Datetime format in xml from Oracle

Tags: excel, xml, oracle

I have a simple requirement to display a time field as a Datetime in xml when converted from excel.
Being new to Oracle field, I'm stuck with a few questions

1. When I run the below query in Oracle my value is displayed as 31-DEC-99 07.45.30.000000000

   `select to_timestamp('1899-12-31 07:45:30', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh:mi:ss') as res from dual;`

Now,I understand that my NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR' and hence the date is shown as 31-DEC-99 but why is the time shown as hh.mm.ss.ffff rather than hh:mm:ss:ffff

2. Is this the reason that when I download this simple file from oracle to excel and convert to xml, the datatype is show as string rather than datetime . I tried a similar exercise directly on excel and we can see the value as datetime on xml  but this doesnt work with excel downloaded from oracle. Where am I going wrong?

[image]

Just to confirm, my requirement here is to get a timestamp displayed in excel properly when downloaded from oracle table and display the same as a datetime field when I open in xml

Answer (score 0):

Is this concerning a BI/XML Publisher report?  If so, you need to do something like this to your dates in your data definition:

```
TO_CHAR(ORDERED_DATE,'MM-DD-YYYY  HH24:MI:SS') ORDERED_DATE
```

Comment: Unfortunately No. This is related to SAP HANA load from excel and datatype being an issue because of the format.

Comment: I have encountered very similar type issues in XML and Excel and the above has resolved the formatting.  You might try something like it anyway..

Answer (score 0):

Realised it was the NLS_DATETIME_FORMAT that I had to worry about. Changed that for my session and worked like a charm.